# in asp.net , c# delete query not execute following error occur

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    s = "delete MAX(id) from emp";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    GridView1.DataBind();
```

> error : Incorrect syntax near '('.

when i try to execute this query above error display at runtime....`enter code here`

Comment: Your delete script is incorrect. `DELETE FROM EMP WHERE ID = ...` [DELETE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)

Comment: Your Sql Query is wrong It sould be `Delete from table where col1 =(select max(col1) from table)`

Answer (score 9):

Correct your Query.

```
s= "delete from emp where id = (select max(id) from emp)";
```